# nsis - uninstall doesn't delete programs folder on start menu

Tags: nsis

The uninstall doesn't delete all the start menu folder of my project :s Only the shortcut in desktop is delete.

```
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\Advanlab\Uninstall.lnk"
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\Advanlab\Website.lnk"
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\Advanlab\Advanlab.lnk"
Delete "$DESKTOP\Advanlab.lnk"
```

All the code in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/h5TURSPx

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `requestexecutionlevel` to disable NT6 compatibility stuff: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Shortcuts_removal_fails_on_Windows_Vista

Comment: Please don't give answers that rely on external links. They make the answer useless when the link becomes inaccessible (like now). You can leave the link but it would be good to quote the relevant section.

Comment: @rdb I did include the solution in my answer.